# Добавление элементов в родительский div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Нужно добавить `div` при нажатии кнопки в другом `div`, у которого такой же родительский класс, что и у кнопки.

У меня есть 7 дней недели, у каждого дня есть кнопка `"Добавить"`, при нажатии на которую в соответствующем дне недели должен появляться `div` с `text` `input`'ом.

Сейчас при нажатии всё добавляется, но не туда. Всегда в понедельник и после кнопки.

Как это исправить?

```js
function addProgram() {
    var objTo = document.getElementById('panel-body')

    var str = '<div class="program"><form><input class="hours" type="text" value=""><input class="mins" type="text" value=""></form></div>';
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str;
    objTo.appendChild(div);
    
    $(".hours").TouchSpin({
        min: 00,
        max: 23,
        step: 1,
        verticalbuttons: true,
        verticalupclass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top',
        verticaldownclass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom'
    });
    $(".mins").TouchSpin({
        min: 00,
        max: 59,
        step: 1,
        verticalbuttons: true,
        verticalupclass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top',
        verticaldownclass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom'
    });
}
```

```css
.panel-collapse > div > button {
    background-color: rgb(228, 118, 58);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    outline-style: none;
}

.panel-collapse > div > button > .glyphicon {
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}

#accordion > div > div > div > a {
    font-size: 32px !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-image: url(images/up.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: right;
    background-position-y: 10px;
}

#accordion > div > div > div > a:hover,
#accordion > div > div > div > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#accordion > div > div > div > a:focus {
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-image: url(images/down.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: right;
    background-position-y: 10px;
}

.input-group .form-control {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
}

.bootstrap-touchspin {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.bootstrap-touchspin .input-group-btn-vertical {
    width: auto;
}

.bootstrap-touchspin-up,
.bootstrap-touchspin-down {
    border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
    height: 21px;
    width: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
}

.bootstrap-touchspin-up > i,
.bootstrap-touchspin-down > i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-touchspin/src/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.css" type="text/css" />


<div class="week panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                    Понедельник
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="addProgram()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                    Вторник
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">
               
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="addProgram()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить</span>
                </button>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                    Среда
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">
                
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="addProgram()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить </span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
        <div class="panel-heading">
           <div class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">
                    Четверг
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">
                
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="addProgram()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive">
                    Пятница
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">
                
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="addProgram()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
        <div class="panel-heading">                        <div class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix">
                    Суббота
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">
                
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="addProgram()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeven">
                    Воскресенье
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">
                
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="addProgram()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: По правилам хорошего тона, `id` элементов должны быть уникальным в документе. В данном случае проблема как раз в этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Вместо привязки по `#panel-body` стоит использовать `.panel-body`.
- Устаревший `onclick` заменил на `$('.panel-body .btn').on('click', function() { ... });`
- Для того, чтобы определить к какому именно `.panel-body` нужно добавить строку, используется `$(this).closest('.panel-body')` внутри обработчика события `click`.
- `.TouchSpin()` инициализируется только для добавленного элемента.

Изменённый JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.panel-body .btn').on('click', function() {
        var jElement = $('<div class="program"><form><input class="hours" type="text" value=""><input class="mins" type="text" value=""></form></div>');
        $(this).closest('.panel-body').append(jElement);
        jElement.find(".hours").TouchSpin({
            min: 00,
            max: 23,
            step: 1,
            verticalbuttons: true,
            verticalupclass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top',
            verticaldownclass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom'
        });
        jElement.find(".mins").TouchSpin({
            min: 00,
            max: 59,
            step: 1,
            verticalbuttons: true,
            verticalupclass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top',
            verticaldownclass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom'
        });
    });
});
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7ygohf0/1/).

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы очень помогли!

Comment: @Daryushka на здоровье.