# Удаление родительского div'a

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Сегодня я [уже спрашивала](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431480) как добавлять новый `div` по нажатию кнопки, а теперь мне нужно удалять строку, и у меня снова ничего не выходит.

По нажатию кнопки у меня появляется `div` с элементами формы и кнопкой `"remove"`. По нажатию на нее `div` должен удаляться, а также должно появляться уведомление о том, что `div` успешно удален. Как это можно сделать?

Я пробовала делать `.remove()`, но видимо неправильно его использую и у меня ничего не происходит.

```js
// Добавление DIVа

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.panel-body .btn').on('click', function() {
        var jElement = $('<div class="program"><form><input class="hours" type="text" value=""><input class="mins" type="text" value=""><button type="button" class="deleteprogram"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove "></span></button></form></div>');

        $(this).closest('.panel-body').append(jElement);
        jElement.find(".hours").TouchSpin({
            min: 00,
            max: 23,
            step: 1,
            verticalbuttons: true,
            verticalupclass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top',
            verticaldownclass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom'
        });
        jElement.find(".mins").TouchSpin({
            min: 00,
            max: 59,
            step: 1,
            verticalbuttons: true,
            verticalupclass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top',
            verticaldownclass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom'
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-touchspin/src/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap-touchspin/src/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.js"></script>

<div class="week panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                                Понедельник
                            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить передачу</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                                Вторник
                            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить передачу</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                                Среда
                            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить передачу</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">
                                Четверг
                            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить передачу</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive">
                                Пятница
                            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить передачу</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix">
                                Суббота
                            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить передачу</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default weekday">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeven">
                                Воскресенье
                            </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div id="panel-body" class="panel-body">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span>Добавить передачу</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Имеет смысл добавить неудачную попытку с `.remove()`  в вопрос. Просто для того, чтобы было видно, что вы пытались решить проблему самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить обработчик события `click` для `.deleteprogram` и в нём удалять всю строку `.program`. Так как `.deleteprogram` добавляются динамически, нужно использовать [delegated event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Итоговое добавление в код (внутри `document.ready`):

```
$('#accordion').on('click', '.deleteprogram', function() {
    $(this).closest('.program').remove();
});
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7ygohf0/2/).

Если нужно уведомление об удалении, можно добавить `alert('Успешно удалено');` после `$(this).closest('.program').remove();`. Либо же использовать какое-либо "красивое" уведомление.